# Aggregate sort by timestamp not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get all the latest comments with username from my post. I tried to get latest record using:

```
"$sort": {
          "rd_comments.created_at": -1
        }
```

Here is the complete query:

```
 [   {
     "$lookup": {
       "from": "userlist",
       "localField": "u_id",
       "foreignField": "u_id",
       "as": "userlist"
     }   },   {
     "$unwind": "$userlist"   },   {
     "$match": {
       "status": {
         "$ne": 2
       }
     }   },   {
     "$skip": 0   },   {
     "$limit": 10   },   {
     "$sort": {
       "rd_comments.created_at": -1
     }   },   {
     "$project": {
       "username": "$userlist.username",
       "_id": 1,
      "comment": 1,
       "created_at": 1
     }   } ]
```

It gives me unsorted result.

**[UPDATED]**

User Document:

```
u_id    |   username
--------------------------
1       |   Shail
--------------------------
2       |   Mukky
--------------------------
```

Comments Documents:

```
c_id    |   u_id   |   comments  | created_at
--------------------------------------------------------
1       |   1      | Nice Post3  | NumberInt(1483405261)
--------------------------------------------------------
2       |   2      | Nice Post3  | NumberInt(1483318861)
--------------------------------------------------------
3       |   2      | Nice Post2  | NumberInt(1488522534)
--------------------------------------------------------
4       |   2      | Nice Post1  | NumberInt(1488522033)
--------------------------------------------------------
5       |   1      | Nice Post2  | NumberInt(1488521530)
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: From what I can tell you will have to unwind the rd_comments array as well to sort on individual entries.

Would you be able to post 1 document so I can see the structure and try to give some more insight?

Comment: @AndyMacleod - I have updated my question with documents, please check. and Yes i have tried to add `"$unwind": "$rd_comments"` but after adding this it shows null in result.

Comment: Can you try moving the $sort before the lookup?
I am assuming you are running the aggregation on the comments collection?

Or if you are making multiple calls, perhaps the sort should move before the skip/limit to ensure you are skipping and limiting on a sorted list?

Comment: Thanks Andy that worked. after moving the $sort before skip/limit its working fine now..